# KeyError: 'search'

Tags: python, flask, internal-server-error

I'm using the genius api to get lyrics to appear on my webpage after typing in an artists name using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from lyrics import scrapeLyricText
from markov import MarkovLyrics

app = Flask(__name__)


def generateArtistLyrics(name):
    songs = scrapeLyricText(name)
    m = MarkovLyrics()

    for song in songs:
        m.populateMarkovChain(song)
    return m.generateLyrics()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lyricsGenerator():
    lyrics = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        artist = request.form['search']
        lyrics = generateArtistLyrics(artist)
    return render_template('home.html', lyrics=lyrics)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My traceback goes as follows:
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'search'

line 21, in lyricsGenerator artist = request.form['search']

I then modified my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from lyrics import scrapeLyricText
from markov import MarkovLyrics

app = Flask(__name__)


def generateArtistLyrics(name):
    songs = scrapeLyricText(name)
    m = MarkovLyrics()

    for song in songs:
        m.populateMarkovChain(song)
    return m.generateLyrics()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lyricsGenerator():
    lyrics = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        artist = request.form.get('search', None)
        lyrics = generateArtistLyrics(artist)
    return render_template('home.html', lyrics=lyrics)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am no longer getting an error, but when i type in an artists name nothing appears on the webpage. But the lyrics do appear in my pycharm terminal. Any suggestions to get the lyrics to appear on my webpage and not just my pycharm terminal.

Here is my html file for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lyrics Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Lyrics Generator</h1>
<p>Here, you can generate lyrics by the artist of your choice!</p>
<form action="{{url_for('lyricsGenerator')}}" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for an artist...">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<p>{{ lyrics }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use jinja in html. <p>{{lyrics}}<p/>

Comment: I added my html file for ref.  unfortunately it still does not work even though i used jinja in my html file

Comment: Did you try to check the contents of the *generated* HTML file (i.e., use "view source" in the browser where you test the web page)? Did you try to check what keys are available in `request.form`?

Comment: Print the lyrics just before render_template and print something in if block to check if the code runs.

Comment: I printed the lyrics and the lyrics printed out in my terminal